# How to connect Quickbooks online with Power BI online?

Tags: powerbi, quickbooks-online

I have a question regarding Power BI public version https://app.powerbi.com. I can`t find the opportunity to take as a source QuickBooks online. Is it possible to connect QB and PowerBI without using the desktop version?

I'm using the trial version. I'd tried to take the source with the help of Data Factory but I didn't find QuickBooks online in the online services. I have only the possibility to take as a source QB through the desktop version, but the desktop doesn't suit me as I want to share the reports with my work team via Live connections to different sources.